# How to embed a Google Street View map using a iframe?

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to embed a Google Street View map using a iframe ([the map](https://maps.google.es/maps?q=barcelona&hl=es&ie=UTF8&ll=41.354134,2.214432&spn=0.32884,0.727158&hnear=Barcelona,%20Catalu%C3%B1a&t=h&z=11&layer=c&cbll=41.384233,2.177893&panoid=cHQCwlORibRoxMqj2m9IVg&cbp=12,0,,0,0))

I just copied the iframe code (from google map) code into a page in my site.

The iframe is shown in the page but its **body** is empty.

What could be the problem?

```
<iframe 
width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
src="https://maps.google.es/maps?q=barcelona&amp;aq=f&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hl=es&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Barcelona,+Catalu%C3%B1a&amp;ll=41.385064,2.173404&amp;spn=0.32884,0.727158&amp;t=h&amp;z=11&amp;layer=c&amp;cbll=41.384233,2.177893&amp;panoid=cHQCwlORibRoxMqj2m9IVg&amp;cbp=12,0,,0,0&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Probably the Google Maps page you are embedding has a frame-buster.

Comment: The [URL works](https://maps.google.es/maps?q=barcelona&aq=f&ie=UTF8&hl=es&hq=&hnear=Barcelona,+Catalu%C3%B1a&ll=41.385064,2.173404&spn=0.32884,0.727158&t=h&z=11&layer=c&cbll=41.384233,2.177893&panoid=cHQCwlORibRoxMqj2m9IVg&cbp=12,0,,0,0&source=embed&output=svembed) for me in a browser.  Embedding the iframe from your link above [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/StreetviewIframe.html).

Comment: Ok I see that it worked for you. Then the problem should be in how my site is rendering the iframe code...

Comment: It works now. Maybe a cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the Url is incorrect. Try something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!4v1526278480320!6m8!1m7!1sCAoSLEFGMVFpcFBJbm9RSGxGbXhHWC1aZFhtOXhkRUhfUTVDVHRIdGdiRUpmUm5i!2m2!1d41.41745213117124!2d2.182604027161005!3f124.5!4f0!5f0.7820865974627469" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```